# dojo grid remove "rowSelector" column

Tags: dojo

Is it possible to remove the `rowSelector` from a `dojo` grid? I'm talking about the area to the left of the first column. I just want to display the columns by themselves. I've search a lot, but can't seem to find ANYTHING on this.

Comment: As you have found out its `rowSelector`. My correction is not that important but just did as `gutters` has a different meaning in `dijit`s.

Comment: From the [API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) :`rowSelector` If set to true, will add a row selector view to this grid. If set to a CSS width, will add a row selector of that width to this grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. when creating the grid, set it's rowSelector property to 0px:

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid(
    {
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '0px'
    },
    $('<div>')[0]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `rowSelector` property for the `DataGrid`:

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid(
    {
        store: store,
        structure: layout
    }
);
```